# I want to pass arraylist between activitys

Tags: android, android-intent

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add(p);
```

i want to send data of list through intent using putStringArray.am failed to retrive trough getIntent().

please give me good syntax to parse data or example code

Comment: First of all, put the code you have tried, so we can built on it.

Comment: exactly what kind of data you want to send? String Array? Post Code

Comment: @Raghunandan Please do not modify the code from OP. user2599624 didn't use generics there.

Comment: @MaciejGórski i din't modify the code. i just edited the question.

Comment: @Raghunandan I belive you did. Changing `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` to `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` is a modification.

Comment: @MaciejGórski no i din't. i don't know if i can roll back but if someone can pls roll back and check

Comment: @Raghunandan Ok. It was a failure of user2599624 incorrectly formatting and StackOverflow incorrectly parsing (stripping `<String>` for display).

Comment: @MaciejGórski i might have done it by chance. how do i roll back the edit to the original post?

Answer (score 2):

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
my_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList inmplements `Serializable`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Assuming your `ArrayList` is of type string

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(p);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", list);
startActivity(i);
```

To receive

```
Intent in = getIntent();
 ArrayList<String> list = in.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> will Serialize. Raw `ArrayList` type is not necessarily capable of Serialization.

Comment: @S.D. valid point. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If your activities run in the same process, that is, if you don't use the android:proces attribute in your manifest file, then you can easily share whatever object you need by using a singleton or a static field. No real need to send the object inside an `Intent` since your activities are synchronized and run in the main UI thread. If you really want to encapsulate it into an `Intent`, you need to implement the `Parcelable` interface (you can also use `Serializable` but it has a greater overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Code for your First Activity

```
    ArrayList<String> arraylist1= new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent intent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle Ext= new Bundle();
    Ext.putStringArrayList("ArrayName", arraylist1);
    intent.putExtras(Ext);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And code for your Second Activity

```
 ArrayList<String> arraylist2= new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    arraylist2 = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Arrayname");
```

Comment: If its works for you. then mark it as an accepted answer